# Exception 'System.OutOfMemoryException'

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

When I try to generate script to a table that contain 500000 records I'm getting an error: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown. Can anybody suggest a solution for backup the table data to clear this error.

Comment: Are you getting this error when running a query from within SQL Server Management Studio or another application?

Comment: What kind of script are you generating - DDL (i.e. CREATE TABLE...) or DML (i.e. INSERT INTO...)?

Comment: actually im trying to take the backup for the table since it has 500000 records, but im getting this exception which avoid me to take the script.i need any Help for this..

Comment: When you say "backup" do you mean you want to export the data to a CSV file (or similar) so you can keep a copy? If you just want to backup the data against failure or data changes why not use the backup features of the database server?

Comment: If you are storing the data in temp table or using Insert into select, it will fill up your temp database space, rather to step by step insert, like first process 100000, then another bunch of records, this will process the data fast and you will not get the out of memory error.

Answer (score 0):

Realistically generating a script with 500,000 inserts is not going to be particularly efficient (assuming you don't run out of RAM of course!). If you need to back up the data I'd look at either backing up the database file itself from the filesystem or alternatively use something like SSIS to export to a file. Both should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, it seems that there are no sufficient memory, and I notice that you are using 32-bit Windows Vista, a 32-bit machine can directly address only 4 GB of memory, and by default, Windows itself reserves the top 2 GB of address space for its own use, which leaves only 2 GB as the maximum size of the VAS (virtual address space) for any application.

However, we could enable 3GB switch to allow application have a VAS of up to 3GB, here is the steps applies to Windows Vista:

Right-click Command Prompt in the Accessories program group of the Start menu. Click Run as Administrator.
At the command prompt, enter "bcdedit /set IncreaseUserVa 3072"
Restart the computer.

Also please refer this thread:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqldatabaseengine/thread/f3736f72-7953-4578-b294-044bb63cd483